# How do I check if a user input exist in Parser.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am stuck trying to figure out how to check the parser database to see if it corresponds to a user input.

For example if the username from the input exists then I toast "Logged in" My issue lies with figuring out how to wrap my head around that concept.

A bit of a newbie to android programming so bare patience, and I believe the error is at *ERROR HERE* in my code.

The error from logical is error: `cannot find symbol variable menu_login`, any help would be appreciated.

```
 package com.example.dan.loginsample;

  import android.content.DialogInterface;
  import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.Uri;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.example.dan.loginsample.R.id;
     import com.example.dan.loginsample.R.layout;
   import com.example.dan.loginsample.R.menu;
  import com.parse.CountCallback;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
   import com.parse.LogInCallback;
   import com.parse.ParseObject;
   import com.parse.ParseQuery;
   import com.parse.ParseUser;

   import java.text.ParseException;
  import java.util.List;


  public class Login extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(layout.activity_login);
    EditText username = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userloginname);
    EditText password = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userpassword);


    TextView neighbourView = new TextView(this);

    Button button_test;
    button_test = (Button) this.findViewById(id.btnLogin);

    button_test.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

            String usersname = username.getText().toString();
            String passwoord = password.getText().toString();


            //ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Parking");
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usersname, passwoord, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                    if (user != null) {
                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.

                    } else {
                        //
                    }
                }



            });
            // return false;
        }
    });
}




@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   //******Error HERE getMenuInflater().inflate(menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}    

}
```

And my XML

```
     <!--  Username Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/username"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/userloginname"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <!--  Password Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#372c24"
        android:text="@string/password"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/userpassword" />
    <!-- Login button -->
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/loginButton"/>
```

Comment: Did you have a menu named **menu_login** in **res/menu** folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code 
from this

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   //******Error HERE getMenuInflater().inflate(menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}
```

into this

```
   @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu1) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(menu.menu_login, menu1);
        return true;
    }
```

the variable name in the argument is also **menu**
. That was your problem